# TkInter - Display multiple images in a grid with scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am new to Tkinter and I am trying to display multiple images in a Window. The images should be displayed in a grid with a scrollbar in the rightmost side of the window. The code below displays scrollbar in the wrong position. How can I place the scroll bar in the rightmost side of the window. Please see the code below.

```
def display_images(folder, root): 
  filenames = os.listdir(folder)
  columns = 10
  image_count = 0
  window = Toplevel(root)
  window.wm_geometry("1200x800")
  canvas = Canvas(window, width = 1200, height = 800)
  canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= "news")
  #canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

  vsb = Scrollbar(window, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
  vsb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
  canvas.configure(yscrollcommand= vsb.set)

  frame_image = Frame(canvas)
  frame_image.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
  #frame_image.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
  #frame_image.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
  canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame_image, anchor="nw")

  for name in filenames:
    image_count += 1
    r, c = divmod(image_count - 1, columns)
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(folder, name))
    resized = im.resize((100,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
    myvar = Label(frame_image, image = tkimage)
    myvar.image = tkimage
    myvar.grid(row=r, column = c)
    #print "here"
  window.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are putting the canvas and the scrollbar into the same grid cell.  Move the scrollbar to column 1, perhaps.  You're also going to need to set the canvas scrollregion to get scrolling to work right.

Comment: Thank you jasonharper!... making column = 1 and changing the dimension of the window and frame helped!